# Is `std::atomic<>` necessary or overkill for `std::condition_variable`?

Tags: c++, multithreading, condition-variable, stdatomic

Suppose there is a simple buffer which serves as the transfer point for some data between a producer and consumer thread. From reading around I have put together the following:

```
const std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::steady_clock> TIMEOUT;
std::condition_variable waitForData;
std::mutex hasDataMutex;
std::atomic<bool> hasData;

void blocking_read(){
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(hasDataMutex);
    if (!hasData) {
        waitForData.wait_until(lock, TIMEOUT,
                           [&]() -> bool { return hasData; });
    }
}

void put_data(char* buf) {
    //...write data into local buffer
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(hasDataMutex);
    hasData = true;
    waitForData.notify_one();
}
```

Assuming the variables were properly initialized: is it necessary, or in the reverse, superfluous to have `hasData` declared `atomic`? Or is it even possible to get away without the mutex if I use `atomic`?

Is there a freely available "Multithreading in C++" write-up somewhere that you would recommend?

Comment: For `_hashData` it is overkill. Since you will always update it from inside a mutex/lock anyway.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12275550/4688321

Comment: Side note: names that begin with an underscore followed by a capital letter (`_TIMEOUT`) and names that contain two consecutive underscores are reserved for use by the implementation. And names that begin with an underscore (`_waitForData`, `_hasDataMutex`, `_hasData`) are reserved for use by the implementation in the global namespace. Don't use them in your code.

Comment: A more serious problem is that your put_data is wrong: you need to notify_all() or notify_one() on your condition variable to actually make the other side wake up.

Also, in mot cases, you'll want to protect the data by the mutex as well -- so, basically, swap the comment and mutex line in your put_data :-)

Comment: @PeteBecker sorry, you are right, I cut this out from a class because I thought that this would add unnecessary noise to the question.

Comment: @ChristianStieber thanks, corrected. Apart from that I will be most grateful for constructive criticism of my naming convention: condition variable, mutex, protected data item and lock - what is the usual prefix/postfix or common name-parts scheme?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Using both `atomic` and `mutex` is overkill here. Worth noting that there are situations where it's useful, like Singleton double-checked locking.
2. If you have C++20, you can use `atomic::wait()` instead of `mutex` and `conditional_variable`.

Comment: Is your 2) also applicable pre-C++20?

Comment: @Vroomfondel Nope, it was introduced in c++20. If you use 11/14/17, you need one of the `conditional_variable::wait*()` functions. I'm going to edit my answer.

Comment: Note that the usual way for singleton double checking is using `call_once` or local `static` (Magic Static), these are expected to employ double-checking themselves. Using `atomic` plus `mutex` for singleton is only needed for something unusual.

Answer (score 2):

The way you have written the code it is not necessary for `_hasData` to be atomic, but you could write the code like this, in which case it *is* necessary:

```cpp
const std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::steady_clock> _TIMEOUT;
std::condition_variable _waitForData;
std::mutex _hasDataMutex;
std::atomic<bool> _hasData;

void blocking_read(){
    if (!_hasData.load()) {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(_hasDataMutex);
        _waitForData.wait_until(lock, _TIMEOUT,
                           [&]() -> bool { return _hasData.load(); });
    }
}

void put_data(char* buf) {
    //...write data into local buffer
    _hasData.store(true);
    _hasDataMutex.lock();
    _hasDataMutex.unlock();
    _waitForData.notify_all();
}
```

This has the advantage that checking `_hasData` in `blocking_read` does not have to acquire the mutex if it is already set. Note that we also don't have to hold the mutex when setting `_hasData` to true, and that it is also not necessary to hold the mutex when calling `notify_all`. However, we still need to acquire the mutex *after* we have set `_hasData` and *before* calling `notify_all` to prevent missed notifications. Otherwise a thread in `blocking_read` could check `_hasData` *before* we set it to true, but only enter `wait_until` *after* we called `notify_all` and thus wait forever.

Note that I adjusted the code to use explicit load/store calls - I prefer this to make it clear that a variable is atomic.

Whether this is actually worth it or not depends on your situation. If all you need is a simple atomic flag like in this example, I would also recommend to use `atomic::wait`, but this is only available from C++20 onward.

**Update:**
Apparently it may still not be clear why this is sufficient, so let be try to elaborate.

Suppose we have two threads - thread A is calling `put_data` while thread B is calling `blocking_read`. The two functions have the following sequences of operations:

- `blocking_read`:
  `_hasData.load() -> _hasDataMutex.lock() -> _waitForData.wait_until()`
- `put_data`:
  `_hasData.store() ->  _hasDataMutex.lock() ->  _hasDataMutex.unlock() -> _waitForData.nofify()`

Note that in `blocking_read` the `wait_until` will check the predicate before going to sleep, and that it implicitly calls `_hasDataMutex.unlock()`. The operations on the mutex are serialized, so we have either:
`A:_hasDataMutex.unlock() -> B:_hasDataMutex.lock()` or `B:_hasDataMutex.unlock() -> A:_hasDataMutex.lock()`, in other words, if A first acquires the mutex, it must unlock it before B can acquire it, or the other way round. Let's discuss these two cases in more detail.

Suppose we have `A:_hasDataMutex.unlock() -> B:_hasDataMutex.lock()`. Thread A is calling `put_data`, so we have the following happens before relation:
`A:_hasData.store() -> A:_hasDataMutex.unlock() -> B:_hasDataMutex.lock() -> B:_waitForData.wait_until()`
So the predicated in `wait_until` is guaranteed to see the updated value is `_hasData`.

Suppose we have `B:_hasDataMutex.unlock() -> A:_hasDataMutex.lock()`. Thread B is executing `blocking_read`, so this unlock happens implicitly in the `wait_until`, atomically with the thread being put to sleep. So we have the following relation:
`B:_waitForData.wait_until() -> A:_hasDataMutex.lock() -> A:_hasDataMutex.unlock() -> A:_waitForData.nofify()`
So in this situation it is guaranteed, that thread B is already asleep and will receive the notification from thread A.

As Peter Cordes has correctly pointed out, we can use more relaxed memory orders. Initially I omitted that for simplicity, but here is the complete example with relaxed memory orders:

```cpp
const std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::steady_clock> _TIMEOUT;
std::condition_variable _waitForData;
std::mutex _hasDataMutex;
std::atomic<bool> _hasData;

void blocking_read(){
    if (!_hasData.load(std::memory_order_acquire)) {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(_hasDataMutex);
        _waitForData.wait_until(lock, _TIMEOUT,
                           [&]() -> bool { return _hasData.load(std::memory_order_relaxed); });
    }
}

void put_data(char* buf) {
    //...write data into local buffer
    _hasData.store(true, std::memory_order_release);
    _hasDataMutex.lock();
    _hasDataMutex.unlock();
    _waitForData.notify_all();
}
```

The first load in `blocking_read` has to use `memory_order_acquire`, so that if we already observe the value written by `put_data`, we establish a happens-before relation (and for that we also need the release-order for the store). The load in the `wait_until` predicate can be completely relaxed, because in that case the happens-before relation is established via the mutex as described above.

Comment: `_hasData.load()` can be `_hasData.load(std::memory_order_acquire)` instead of the default `seq_cst`.  This is more efficient on some ISAs, including ARMv8.3 for LDAPR, and PowerPC.

Comment: Please don't get angry if I'm obtuse, but isn't it still possible - following your reasoning - that the read() thread waits forever: it runs into the `if()` and gets immediately preempted, the put() does its work and then read() continues - why would aquiring the mutex in between where this action is invisible to read(), help us?

Comment: Why would I be angry? If it is not clear, then obviously I did not do a good job explaining it. :) I have updated my answer with a more detailed explanation, and also added the code with more relaxed memory orders as pointed out by @PeterCordes